# Dynamic select from views in Java

Tags: java, oracle, select

Hi im new in java and im trying to create a generic method to perform select to views with dynamic conditions and order that receive the name of the object (view), condition and order

I found criteria api but you always need to send the class

This is an example i tried to implement but is not working

```
protected <E extends Object> List<E> listarPorCriteria(String nombreCampo, String valor, String criterio , Class<E> tipoRetorno) throws Exception {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();      
        CriteriaQuery<tipoRetorno> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(tipoRetorno.class);      
        Root<tipoRetorno> from = criteriaQuery.from(tipoRetorno.class);
        List<T> criteria = new ArrayList<>();

        if (criterio != null && !criterio.isEmpty())        {
            if (criterio == CriteriosBase.IGUAL) {
                criteria.add((T) criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get("nombreCampo"), valor));

                criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.like(from.get("nombreCampo"), valor));
            }

        }


        criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteria.toArray(new criteria[0])));

        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        return q.getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe more what "not working" means?  What result do you get and what were you expecting?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not using Spring JdbcTemplate for that? It would be much easier for you with dynamic data.